# execAndWait interceptor not working with validation

Tags: java, validation, jsp, struts2

I am getting `NullPointerException` when using `execAndWait` interceptor with `validate()` method. In `index.jsp`, I have one `textfield` for `firstName`. When I do submit, it first `validate` that string in `Action` class with validate method. Then it goes to `execute` method. In output I am getting `NullPointerException` for `firstName` field not found in `validate` method. Somewhere I came to know that, `execAndWait` runs in separate thread, that's why this problem arises. I want to know how to resolve this problem. File wise code below:

**`index.jsp`:**

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <s:actionerror />
    <s:actionmessage />
    <s:form action="go" method="post">
        <s:textfield name="fname" label="First-Name" />
        <s:submit value="enter"></s:submit>
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="abc" extends="struts-default">

        <interceptors>
            <interceptor-stack name="myStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait"></interceptor-ref>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <action name="go" class="pack.GoAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="myStack" />
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/failure.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
            <result name="wait">/wait.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**`GoAction.java`:**

```java
package pack;
import java.sql.*;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
public class GoAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private User user;
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    @Override
    public User getModel() {
        System.out.println("****inside getModel()****");
        user=new User();
        return user;
    }

    public void validate(){
        System.out.println("****inside validate****");
        if(user.getFname().length()<4){
            this.addFieldError("fname", "first name can not be less than 5");
            System.out.println("console: first name can not be less than 5 "+user.getFname());
        }
        if(user.getFname().length()==0){
            this.addFieldError("fname", "first name found empty");
        }
    }

    public String execute(){
        System.out.println("****inside execute****");
        String returnValue="";
        int i=0;
        Connection con=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        PreparedStatement ps=null;
        if(user.getFname().equals("zebra")){
            System.out.println("First-Name : zebra : not allowed.");
            this.addActionMessage("First-Name : zebra : not allowed");
            return "failure";
        }
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "hibernate", "hibernate");
            ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into table1 values(?)");
            ps.setString(1, user.getFname());
            i=ps.executeUpdate();
            if(i!=0){
                returnValue="success";
                this.addActionMessage("data successfully inserted");
                System.out.println("ok");
            }
            else{
                returnValue="failure";
                System.out.println("not ok");
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("E x c e p t i o n    o c c u r r e d  !!!!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

**`wait.jsp`:**

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Wait...</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="images/animation_processing.gif" />
</body>
</html>
```

**`success.jsp`:**

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    Success !!
    <br>
    <s:actionmessage />
</body>
</html>
```

**OUTPUT-Screens (step-wise)**
[image]

[image]

[image]

however value got inserted in Database:
[image]

**Console OUtPUT**

```
****inside getModel()****
****inside validate****
****inside execute****
Apr 26, 2015 4:30:48 PM org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper warn
WARNING: Could not find token mapped to token name token
ok
****inside getModel()****
****inside validate****
Apr 26, 2015 4:30:50 PM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher error
SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pack.GoAction.validate(GoAction.java:35)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doBeforeInvocation(ValidationInterceptor.java:251)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

After a bit of browsing, I came to know that `execAndWait` runs in a separate thread and is NOT able to get the value of `user.getFname()`. Can anyone help me resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change the logic of the validation method

```
public void validate(){
    System.out.println("****inside validate****");
    if(user.getFname() == null || user.getFname().length()==0){
        this.addFieldError("fname", "first name found empty");
    } else
    if(user.getFname().length()<4){
        this.addFieldError("fname", "first name can not be less than 5");
        System.out.println("console: first name can not be less than 5 "+user.getFname());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's saying "first name found empty". Even though its inserting the value to db. Also, If I remove the `execAndWait` interceptor entry from `struts.xml` file, then there is NO problem with old code of validate method.

Comment: Is it saying before or after the values are inserted to the db?

Comment: first of all sorry for reacting too late. This is the Console output that I am getting : ****inside getModel()****
****inside validate****
****inside execute****
Apr 26, 2015 10:33:00 PM org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper warn
WARNING: Could not find token mapped to token name token
ok
****inside getModel()****
****inside validate****

Comment: can you tell me...why is it entering in `getModel()` and `validate()` methods again?  If I remove `execAndWait` interceptor entry from struts.xml, then the output shows: `****inside getModel()**** ****inside validate**** ****inside execute****`

Comment: You should read how [`execAndWait`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28690868/573032) interceptor works, it returns a `wait` result after some timeout to call your action again and again until the action is executed. If it doesn't have parameters they won't be set to the action and validation always fails. If you remove `validation` interceptor from the stack, or simply don't use `execAndWait` interceptor with post requests.

Comment: : ) thanks for explaining `execAndWait` in such simple language. But, if this is the scene, how can I keep using this interceptor along with validation logic. Is there some way out.

Comment: once the execute method has been hit, then is there any way to stop `execAndWait` from waiting.

Comment: You can configure it using parameters described in the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution lies in the way `execAndWait` interceptor works and also with the way struts2 framework calls methods (`getModel()`, then `validate()` and then `execute`). Also note that `execAndWait` runs in different thread. You can't use ActionContext because it is a ThreadLocal. This means if you need to access, for example, session data, you need to implement SessionAware rather than calling ActionContext.getSession().

----how execAndWait workds------

as told by @Roman C and also in API Docs

> - `execAndWait` returns a wait result after some timeout to call your action again and again until the action is executed. If it doesn't have parameters they won't be set to the action and validation always fails.

The above program is throwing `NullPointerException` due to the fact, that `execAndWait` interceptor is calling `getModel()` (along with `validate()`) repeatedly after every 1 second interval (see in wait.jsp `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;"/>`).

So when it calls `getModel()` again, then it is setting the raw `new User();`object i.e. without any parameter `fname`. So, after `getModel()`, it enters into `validate()` again. And this time it finds `fname` to be `null`. Therefore to resolve above problem just replace the `GoAction` class with below code:

**GoAction**

```
package pack;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
public class GoAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User>,SessionAware {
    private SessionMap<String, Object> sm;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private User user;
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    @Override
    public User getModel() {
        System.out.println("****inside getModel()****");
        User u=(User) sm.get("user");
        if(u==null){
            user=new User();
        }
        else{
            user=u;
        }
        return user;
    }

    public void validate(){
        sm.put("user", user);
        User u=(User) sm.get("user");
        System.out.println("^^^"+u.getFname());
        System.out.println("****inside validate****");
        if(u.getFname().length()<4){
            this.addFieldError("fname", "first name can not be less than 5");
            System.out.println("console: first name can not be less than 5 "+user.getFname());
        }
    }

    public String execute() throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("****inside execute****");
        String returnValue="";
        int i=0;
        Connection con=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        PreparedStatement ps=null;
        if(user.getFname().equals("zebra")){
            System.out.println("First-Name : zebra : not allowed.");
            this.addActionMessage("First-Name : zebra : not allowed");
            return "failure";
        }
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "hibernate", "hibernate");
            ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into table1 values(?)");
            ps.setString(1, user.getFname());
            i=ps.executeUpdate();
            if(i!=0){
                returnValue="success";
                this.addActionMessage("data successfully inserted");
                System.out.println("ok");
            }
            else{
                returnValue="failure";
                System.out.println("not ok");
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("E x c e p t i o n    o c c u r r e d  !!!!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> sm) {
        this.sm=(SessionMap<String, Object>) sm;
    }
}
```

in this code I am checking for `user` object stored session map in `getModel()` method. If NOT found : `new User()`. If found : return it.